# Facebook Audience Network 6.0.0 Update for Unity is required

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-audience-network

Facebook Audience Network has update its android sdk to 6.0.0, due to this, Android SDK takes com. facebook file with 6.0.0, but they didn't update unity sdk.

Due to this, Facebook Audience network give error of "AdSetting".

If I separately integrate current SDK, it works fine and resolve the file with `com.facebook.android.audience-network-sdk-5.11.0`
but when I resolve dependency with admob, it give `com.facebook.android.audience-network-sdk-6.0.0` and after building, it give the following error

```
2020/09/04 13:03:13.663 28257 28287 Error Unity AndroidJavaException:
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='setAdListener' 
 signature='(Lcom.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdExtendedListener;)V' in class 
 Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you found the solution?

Comment: No, not yet. I can only fix this issue by putting old file again in place of 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

facebook remove setAdListener deprecated APIs in last audience network SDK 6.0.0, check the new method in facebook developers :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/changelog-android/

Comment: They should update their unity SDK then because changing their script will result in more errors

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Audience Network SDK Unity is not able to run with the latest Google libraries like if you have third-party plugins in your project e.g GoogleAdMob or Chartboost.

After resolving of android libraries the following library is added:
com.facebook.android.audience-network-sdk-6.0.0.aar which is not compatible with unity

Because Facebook Audience Network SDK 6 for unity is not live yet, so you have to replace that library with this one:
com.facebook.android.audience-network-sdk-5.11.0

I recommend you to first install the FBAN in your unity project. Then Resolve the libraries after that copy this"com.facebook.android.audience-network-sdk-5.11.0" for the library for later use. Now import other third-party plugins you want to use for your project. Resolve the library and uncheck the auto-resolve, delete the wrong version of FBAN and add the saved version in your project. You are done.